# count number of occurencecs of string in text NOT substring

Tags: python, string, count

probably a pretty simple solution but I just can't find a google answer because the moment you type sub-string in google search i get bombarded with wrong answers i don't need

I have a string: `text = "Hello, how are you doing doing howhow abhowab"`

I would like to count the number of occurrences of "how" (**1**) **NOT** the amount of occurrences of the sub-string "how" (4).

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex with `\b` which means *word boundary*

```
import re

sentence = "Hello, how are you doing doing howhow abhowab"
word = "how"
nb_matches = len(re.findall(rf"\b{word}\b", sentence))
print(nb_matches)  # 1
```

You can also split the sentence in words, then `count`

```
nb_matches = sentence.split().count(word)
print(nb_matches)  # 1
```

Comment: r"\s(h|H)ow\s" if you want to handle cases with capitalization (how or How)

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "Hello, how are you doing doing howhow abhowab"
    
word = "how"

#split the text into an array of words
wordlist = text.split()
    
#print out the number of occurrences of the word
print(wordlist.count(word))
```

Comment: Code-only answer are not to be preferred. A nice explanation would be nice, to help the OP more ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to only detect `'how'` and not `'howhow'` you could look for the substring `' how '`

```
text = "Hello, how are you doing doing howhow abhowab"
print(text.count(' how '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "Hello, how are you doing doing howhow abhowab"
from collections import Counter
Counter(text.split(' '))['how']
2
```

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) `is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any  integer value including zero or negative counts`

Another way of doins is using `operator`

```
import operator
operator.countOf("Hello, how are you doing doing howhow abhowab how".split(' '),"how")
2
```